# IPad/IPhone, iOS and Android network programming, push or pull data from server

Tags: android, ios, networking

I am developing a turn based game with multiple clients for iOS and Android.  I'm using JSON and standard HTTPS encapsulation to transport the data.  I am using the NSURLRequest (iOS) and DefaultHttpClient, HttpPost (Android) method to make the request and have completed some sample code to test connecting to a web server and returning data back to the client. (this works fine)

After a game has been started, I would prefer that the server send updates to the client(s), rather than have the client constantly 'poll' the server.  I think the push method would be more efficient for the game and for the device/network.

Although push based connections typically require and open 'socket', as the client could be behind firewalls, proxies etc.

Do I just have to settle for the client code to poll the server at intervals? (5 second would be necessary for optimum game performance).

Comment: Use pull, same mechanism can be used in all the applications (iOS, Android). In that you do not need to keep the connection open/ socket listening all the time.